# Return element on top of element using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html structure:

```
<table class="name">....</table>
<ul class="other">...<ul>
```

When a sibling of `.other` is clicked, I am able to get to and target the `.other` ul element. But how would I go outside of that to then target the table `.name` on top?

Comment: can you please add relevant javascript / jquery and also elaborate more on issue you are facing

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/prev/ or $(".other").closest().find(".name")

Comment: with closest() you go outside

Comment: I don't understand. The table *is* a sibling of `.other`, so when you say you already manage to get a sibling in another scenario, then why would it be different for *this* particular sibling? Are you sure you are using the word "sibling" in its real meaning?

Comment: table is not a sibling it would be above it @trincot

Comment: What do you mean with "above"? You mean "before"? The HTML code you have included in your question has both elements as each other's siblings. If you say they are not siblings, then please correct your HTML, because currently they are.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.other').prev('.name');`

Would be the correct method to get an element on top of the element in question.

Comment: That is not "on top of". That gets the preceding sibling. I think you are mixing up terms in your question.